# Hashmap 1 key 2 values - using containsvalue

Tags: java, hashmap

Somewhere in stackoverflow i found solution about 2 values.

```
public class Pair<A, B> {
    A first = null;
    B second = null;

    Pair(A first, B second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public A getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(A first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public B getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void setSecond(B second) {
        this.second = second;
    }

}

public static HashMap<Player, Pair<HorseModifier, LivingEntity>> P_and_h = 
      new HashMap<Player,Pair<HorseModifier, LivingEntity>>();;
```

And the question:

```
P_and_h.put(p, new Pair(hm, hm.getHorse()));

if(P_and_h.containsValue(HorseModifier))` - dont working ( this is first object)
```

Comment: the `containsValue` method will check for a matching value, which in this case is a `Pair`, not a `HorseModifier`. And start your variable names with a lowercase letter. And, you seem to be calling `containsValue` with a class name.

Comment: .. and since `Pair` does not implement `equals` it will only find the contained value if it is the exact same instance (= you can't create another `new Pair(hm, hm.getHorse())` since that's a different instance)

Comment: Also, its recommended to override equals and hashCode(not needed in this case but good practice) for your Pair class.

Answer (score 1):

you should check with `Pair` object like this `P_and_h.containsValue(pair)`.

> containsValue() Returns true if this map maps one or more keys to the specified value.

Comment: I need to put(to containsvalue) there two values to find one value?

Comment: @user2652995 Since you put a pair in there, yes. If you want to find a pair using a `HorseModifier` you'll need to iterate over the entire thing. A better way to go would be to have: `HashMap<Player,HorseModifier>`

Comment: @user2652995 as @Keyser told.you put a `Pair` in map.So you have check with that then only to get correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Since the value is of type `Pair` you should search for a `Pair` and pass it as parameter in the method `containsValue()`;
You should also override `hasCode()` and `equals()` if you want to find the "meaningfully" equal objects, namely the objects which contain the same fields, in your case the same `HorseModifier` and `LivingEntity`. Else it checks only if the reference you pass refers to an Object which exists in `Map`, irrespective of its fields.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [Map#containsKey()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
if (P_and_h.containsKey(p)) {
  // ...
}
```

or, pass the same `Pair`

```
if (P_and_h.containsValue(new Pair(hm, hm.getHorse()))) {
  // ...
}
```

Using `containsValue()` is **not** recommended. Since, it can't leverage the hashing (which is done for keys not their values) it would give you a terrible performance. More info at [Map#containsValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue%28java.lang.Object%29)

> This operation will probably require time linear in the map size for most implementations of the Map interface.

Answer (score 0):

Too bad, this is **not** possible!

By instict i would say `Pair` needs to implement `equals()` but `containsKey` dont check by using `equals()`, it checks for identity using `==`.

Too bad, you cant use HashMap.

- Implement HashMap and override `containsKey` and `containsValue`.
- Or may even better, create your own Map.